# is there and MongoDB GUI tool where we can create Aggregation queries online

Tags: mongodb, nosql, nosql-aggregation

I have seen NoSQLBooster but this only supports "find" function in its visual query builder.

Is there and mongodb tool where we can use aggregation pipeline functions and functions like "set" "findandmodify" visually ?

eventually i want to generate mongoddb c# code.

can we select properties and what we want and it could generate queries and c# code like

```
     var update = Builders<xxxx>.Update.Set(xxxx, xxxxx);
            await collection.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out MongoDB Compass.  It has an aggregation pipeline builder.

https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass

Compass will export the pipeline query to C#, as well as Java, Python, and Node.

Comment: can we visually use functions like 

"UpdateManyAsync" ?

Comment: UpdateMany (including UpdateManyAsync) are not aggregation pipeline stage operators.  These are mql operators.  Any async operator will be driver specific.  Probably c# driver in your use case.